# Determine if TIFF image is grayscale or color using Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-studio, tiff, converters, grayscale

1. What Property or GetMethod can tell me whether a TIFF file is grayscale or color?
   Is there some book that explains Palettes, PixelFormat, ImageAttributes, Flags?
2. The user may what/need to convert a color TIFF image to grayscale. How is this done
   in Visual Basic?

Comment: https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags.html

Answer (score 0):

Thru your help I found LibTiff. It answered almost all my questions. So here is some code that works.

```
Imports BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic

Dim tifLeft As Tiff
Dim fileLeft As String

fileLeft = TNpath + "\" + fileNames(q)
tifLeft = Tiff.Open(fileLeft, "r") ' Tiff to read tags

 ' --- Get Gray or Color 
 Dim value = tifLeft.GetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC)
 Dim GorC As Integer = value(0).ToInt()
 imgLeftColor = False
  If GorC > 1 Then
      imgLeftColor = True
  Else
      imgLeftColor = False
  End If
```